# How can I find all rows that match a criteria and return matching rows in R?

Tags: r, correlation

I have two data frames, one for SNPs and one for genes.

For each gene, if the SNP position is within the window size, I want to return that row to a data frame. Then I want to find the correlation between that particular SNP and that gene if its in the window. I'm currently using R.

Genes data frame :

```
Chr Start   End sample1 sample2 sample3
10  100015109   100015443   2   1   1
10  100365832   100368960   1   0   2
10  100486970   100487277   2   1   0
```

SNPs data frame:

```
SNP CHROM   POSITION    sample1 sample2 sample3
rs3766180   1   1478153 1   1   2
rs7540231   1   1506035 2   2   0
rs2272908   1   1721479 1   1   2
rs10907187  1   1759054 0   1   2
```

I have this code so far, but I'm not sure if I'm making the right iteration. I want to iterate through the genes and check which snps are located within the window sizes and find r-squared between the that snp and that gene. For example, if snp1's position is located in the start and end range of the gene, then select that row and then find r-squared between these two rows. I think my loop is wrong and there could be an easier way. Please help.

```
snps <- as.matrix(read.table("snps.txt", header=T, sep="\t"))
genes <- as.matrix(read.table("genes.txt", header=T, sep="\t"))

#Set upper and lower bounds
size = 1000000
window_left = genes$cnvStart - size
window_right = genes$cnvEnd + size
snp_pos <- snps$POS
snp <- snps$ID


for (s in 1:nrow(snps)){
  for(g in 1:nrow(genes)){
    if (snp_pos >window_left & snp_pos < window_right){
         corr.matrix2 <- (cor(t(s),t(g),use="pairwise.complete.obs", method="pearson"))
      new_snps <- cbind(snp, snps[,-3])
    }
  }
}
```

My desired output is a table of r-squared values for each selected snp-gene comparison.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nev

Comment: to help, a minimal reproducable example with a desired output would help me understand the issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I edited the post. I hope that clarifies what I'm having trouble with. Please let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: What do you expect to do with the "r-squared". What do you think it means? I recommend you to see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination). How big is your data?

Comment: What is the output of this code? Do you get any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay there is still someting i'm unclear on.

First: none of the positions in `SNP` dataframe is within the `Start` and `End` in the `Genes` dataframe - I've made an example where they are.

Second: you want to use the row to correlate with another row under the sample1,2 and 3?

e.i if you wanted these to row.

```
Chr Start   End sample1 sample2 sample3
10  100015109   100015443   2   1   1 <----  THIS ROW?

SNP CHROM   POSITION    sample1 sample2 sample3
rs3766180   1   1478153 1   1   2    <---- AND THIS ROW?

My understanding is that you want to correlate   2   1   1  with  1   1   2
```

I've got a working example now:

```
Genes<-data.frame(Chr=c(10,10,10),Start=c(100015109,100365832,100486970),End=c(100015443,100368960,100487277),sample1=c(2,1,2),sample2=c(1,0,1),sample3=c(1,2,0))
SNP <- data.frame(SNP= c("rs3766180","rs7540231","rs2272908"),CHROM=c(1,1,1),POSITION=c(100015200,100365831,100486971),sample1=c(1,2,1),sample2=c(1,2,1),sample3=c(2,0,2))

> Genes
  Chr     Start       End sample1 sample2 sample3
1  10 100015109 100015443       2       1       1
2  10 100365832 100368960       1       0       2
3  10 100486970 100487277       2       1       0
> SNP
        SNP CHROM  POSITION sample1 sample2 sample3
1 rs3766180     1 100015200       1       1       2
2 rs7540231     1 100365831       2       2       0
3 rs2272908     1 100486971       1       1       2

CorTestMatrix <- data.frame()

for (igene in 1:nrow(Genes)) { # for every gene
        curGeneRow <- Genes[igene ,] # take that row
        for (isnp in 1:nrow(SNP)) { # for every SNP
                cursnp <- SNP[isnp ,] # take that row of SNP
                if (cursnp$POSITION > curGeneRow$Start & curGeneRow$End > cursnp$POSITION) { # is the SNP in the Gene Window=
                        x<-as.numeric(as.vector(cursnp[,4:ncol(cursnp)])) # if you want the row from Position, 
                        y<-as.numeric(as.vector(curGeneRow[,4:ncol(curGeneRow)])) # and want the row from End
                        corTest <- cor.test(x,y) # correlate those two 
                        CurTestMatrix <- data.frame(GeneChr=curGeneRow$Chr,SNP=levels(droplevels(cursnp$SNP)),test=as.numeric(corTest[3]))
                        # saves some info from both Dataframes and the p Value from the cortest.
                        # you need edit this to get additional data. 
                        CorTestMatrix <- smartbind(CorTestMatrix,CurTestMatrix)

                }

        }
}

> CorTestMatrix
    GeneChr       SNP      test
1:1      10 rs3766180 0.6666667
1:2      10 rs3766180 0.6666667
2        10 rs2272908 0.3333333
```

There might be a much faster way to do this, but a for loop is simple to edit and play around with. I've made it so that the first and third row of the SNP should be within the Start and End of GeneRow 1 and 3 respectively equallying 2 correlation tests.

I would advise correcting for non-normally distributed samples if needed:

```
sp_Cov1 <- shapiro.test(x);sp_Cov2 <- shapiro.test(y) # correction for non-normallity
if(sp_Cov1[2] < 0.05 | sp_Cov2[2] < 0.05) {correlationToUse = 'kendall'
} else {correlationToUse = 'pearson'}

 corTest <- cor.test(x,y,method=correlationToUse)
```

To avoid a biased estimate of the `p$value`

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. I completely forgot to grab examples that the SNP would fall in that range. Sorry about that. But, yes I want to correlate that row in the snp df with the row in the gene df. I see what you mean for the estimate bias. I will give this a try and validate!! Thank you.

Comment: Cool, anything else, then indicate that the answer is correct :D

Comment: Sure will. Just finished giving it a run. I get this error:                               Error in UseMethod("droplevels") : 
  no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class "NULL"             I thought drop levels was part of the base package. I'm not sure why this error comes up.

Comment: hmm it is the `levels(droplevels(cursnp$SNP))`  in my example it is a factor,  what is it in the actual data?,  can you run `typeof(cursnp$SNP)` and `class(cursnp$SNP)` and post results ? you can just set `isnp=1`

Comment: Sure.  Here is the result  > typeof(cursnp$SNP)
[1] "NULL"
> class(cursnp$SNP)
[1] "NULL"

Comment: Maybe I have to set the factors when I load my data

Comment: so you do `cursnp <- SNP[1,]` and then `typeof(cursnp$SNP)` and `class(cursnp$SNP)` and SNP is a dataframe? you can do `typeof(SNP)` `class(SNP)` aswell. There's something up with that format.

Comment: It all depends on how you want to store the data, what does cursnp$SNP output when you have it subsettede like that.

Comment: I mislabeled it. Instead of SNP, it was ID. It has given me an output. I'm going to look at it more and continue. Thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: One more question. I forgot to make sure its on the same chr, but I added it in the if statement, that should be ok right? Like such:                                              if (cursnp$CHROM==curGeneRow$Chr & cursnp$POS > curGeneRow$cnvStart & curGeneRow$cnvEnd > cursnp$POS)

Comment: For some reason, it keeps giving me all comparisons, even the ones no in the window. Can we move this to chat so I can show you what I've changed?

Answer (score 1):

I copy your code and comment it

```
snps <- as.matrix(read.table("snps.txt", header=T, sep="\t"))
genes <- as.matrix(read.table("genes.txt", header=T, sep="\t"))
```

It is not wrong but it is better to make clear in the name which kind of file is, if they are separated by tab they are tsv files (*t*ab *s*eparated *f*iles). This way you can open them easier with other programs (Microsoft Excel or similar)

```
#Set upper and lower bounds
size = 1000000
window_left = genes$cnvStart - size
window_right = genes$cnvEnd + size
snp_pos <- snps$POS
snp <- snps$ID
```

Here you set the variables, but you get vectors, so snp or snp_pos are vectors. You must known which kind of data you want if you want to use it later.

```
for (s in 1:nrow(snps)){
  for(g in 1:nrow(genes)){
```

After getting the information you need of the data frames you iterate both by snps number of rows and genes' number of rows. Why do you not use the snp_pos and snp variables?

```
    if (snp_pos >window_left & snp_pos < window_right){
```

Here you are comparing all you want, you don't need the two previous for loops.

```
         corr.matrix2 <- (cor(t(s),t(g),use="pairwise.complete.obs", method="pearson"))
```

You don't use the variables selected to create the pairwise correlation. You should use your variables. I would also recommend to plot the correlations for a visual comparison. (You might need them too)

```
      new_snps <- cbind(snp, snps[,-3])
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't create a table it joins to vectors in one data frame which is not a table.

I haven't test it but I would do something like this:

```
snps <- as.matrix(read.table("snps.txt", header=T, sep="\t"))
genes <- as.matrix(read.table("genes.txt", header=T, sep="\t"))

#Set upper and lower bounds
size = 1000000
window_left = genes$cnvStart - size
window_right = genes$cnvEnd + size

in_window = snps[snps$POS >window_left & snps$POS < window_right]
corr.matrix2 <- (cor(in_window$, in_window$ ,use="pairwise.complete.obs", method="pearson"))
```

I don't really known which correlation do you want to do, so you should change the first two arguments of the cor function (The incomplete in_window$). I guess you want to compare which samples have which SNP. But that's another question ;)

Comment: Ok, I was creating two loops and then doing the same thing for my condition. No wonder I wasn't getting anything. I will try both of these methods and then validate. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't get anything in my version. Not even an error. I'm still running these two methods now. Will update when I finish. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Do you have a print statement or something otherwise you won't known which is the result. Add `print corr.matrix2` to visualize it.